# ехешник, генерирующий другой ехешник

Tags: c++, exe

Нужно создать исполняемый ехе-файл, который при запуске будет генерировать другой ехе-файл.
К примеру, первый файл запрашивает строку консолью, а второй, сгенерированный первым, будет эту строку выводить.

Если я (+/- способный студень 3 курса программной инженерии) имею критически неполный взгляд на это дело и це гораздо сложнее, чем мне показалось, можете так и написать, что я балбес, и я это не потяну, я пойму.

Comment: Непонятна цель всего этого. Одна программа должна передать строку другой? По сети, или как-то еще? Вобщем, непонятно, что вы такое хотите...

Comment: Что значит "генерирующий"? Вам нужно, чтобы первый экзешник обязательно скидывал на диск и запускал другой экзешник? Ну тогда как-нибудь запакуйте второй экзешник в первый, предварительно их откомпилировав. Правда на вашу прогу могут потом ругаться антивирусы, так как подобным образом ведут себя некоторые вирусы.

Comment: Ваш exe-шник может создавать текстовый файл с простейшей C++ программой. Потом вызываете компилятор и далее запускаете результат компиляции. (Если скажут, что это нечестно, то вам придется скачать какой-нибудь простенький компилятор и вкомпилировать его в свою программу)

Comment: Получается лямбда функция на уровне операционной системы. Забавно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. пишите программу котороя читает строку из собственных ресурсов, и
   выводит ее на экран.
2. пишите программы которая:

2.1. извлекает бинарные данные из собственных ресурсов и сохраняет их как    отдельный файл.

2.2. запрашивает строку у пользователя

2.3. вносит эту строку в ресурсы файла, полученного на шаге 2.1.

В качестве бинарных ресурсов на п.2 используете программу, полученную в п.1.

Использование ресурсов win32:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources